# How to securely send your user and hashed password to a server?

Tags: encryption, authentication, passwords, web-application, webserver

I'm making a user system for an app I'm developing, and I have a client side (the mobile app itself) and a server side (where the database remains) for it. The app sends `get` and `post` petitions to the server and the server processes them and sends the information to the client.

I've been reading recently that for sending passwords between client and server it is recommended that you send from the app the hashed password (using an algorithm like SHA-256) and the server compares that hashed value with the one he has stored in the database, then if they are equal, the server marks the user as logged in.

But I have a question: doesn't that make possible that some evil hacker gets the hashed values and uses that information to log in as the user? I mean, this mechanism only avoids that evil hackers see how the true password is, as you don't store it in its original form anywere. How do I make then the system more secure to avoid that?

Comment: That is absolutely wrong. You always hash on the server side.

Comment: See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords

Comment: But then there's a moment that you send to the server the password without encryption. That is unsafe, isn't it? Okay, i did not see the last comment you made xD I'm going to check that out now.

Comment: All logins must occur over HTTPS. WIthout that there's not really any security